# C: moving elements from one list to another

Tags: c, list, linked-list

(The program is in C) I've got my self-made lists here:
[image]

- a1, a2, a3... and b1, b2... are structures, each one stores some data and a pointer (next) pointing to the next structure (the one below them in the drawing),
- temp, top1, head and head 1 are just pointers to these structures, they store no other data,

And I want to change the situation to the following:
[image: I'm always moving the first element of the list on the left and putting in at the end of the list on the right]

I'm always moving the first element of the list on the left and putting in at the end of the list on the right

I'm not sure now if I need *temp*, I most likely don't. **How do I achieve what is shown in the second picture?**

I obviously can't use a1, a2, a3, b1 and b2 in an obvious way since they don't have names, they're allocated dynamically by malloc (yes, I know it sucks, but before I officially know that, my teacher wants me to learn all about it for some reason).

Comment: Are you always moving the *first* element from the list, or is this just an example?

Comment: @BoPersson I'm always taking the first element from the list and always putting it in the end of the second list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

```
 while(head!=NULL)
 {
    head=head->next;
    top1->next=temp;
    top1=temp;
    temp=head;
 }
```

**listA** is the list on the left and I am assuming that **top1** must be pointing the last node of **listB** (list on the right).

Comment: The second line is what I said I can't do, there's no such thing as b2 in my program, it is allocated with malloc, so it has no name.

Comment: @Ania yes, in C there are no names for the dynamically allocated, By B2  I mean head1->next->next-next. head1->next is B1, head1->next->next is B2.

Comment: but I don't want to do it just once, I want to always take the first element from the list on left and put it at the end of the list on right. The list will have over 13 thousand records, I can't always write head1->next->next->next->next->(...). That's what I made top1 for.

Comment: @Ania edited my answer for accommodating as many nodes as needed.

Comment: Thank you, I need to take some time to analyze it since I'm pretty fresh when it comes to lists not from the library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the node you're moving (you have that in temp).

`temp = list_a->head;`

2. Shift head of first list to the second node.

`list_a->head = list_a->head->next;`

3. Add tmp to the last node second list. (last node is stored in top1)

`top1->next = temp;`

4. The moved node is pointing to the new head of the first list, so delete the pointer.

`temp->next = NULL;`

5. It's not needed, but the picture says that temp needs to hold pointer to the new head of list_a.

`temp = list_a->head;`

6. Shift top1 to point to the moved node.

`top1 = top1->next;`

If my answer isn't clear enough, try to draw this in steps.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you don't need the `temp` pointer at all. Pointer `head` is enough for managing a link list. But for fast insert at the end of the list you can always maintain a `last` pointer to pointing at the last node.

In your structure `temp` pointer is not playing any role. At any moment of time you can create a `temp` pointer for manipulating the list and assign the address of second node of the list like below:-

```
   temp = head->next;
```

If the structure in both the list are of same type you can easily moving each element to the next list. Else in the second structure you have to introduce one more `next` pointer which can store the address of element of first list.

To move element first you need to reach at the last element (based on your requirement) and you can achieve that like below:-

```
 temp = head1;
 while(temp->next != NULL)
   temp = temp->next;
//now while loop will break once temp point at the last node i.e. b2 in your case
  //Now if you want to move all the element of the first list just do like below

 temp->next = head;

 //if you want to move only the first element a1 you can do it like below
 temp->next = head;
 // now you have to move the head node like below in the first list
 head = head->next;
```